# Assign control vs. treatment groupings randomly based on % for more than 2 groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, experimental-design

Piggy backing off my own previous question [python pandas: assign control vs. treatment groupings randomly based on %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548404/python-pandas-assign-control-vs-treatment-groupings-randomly-based-on)

Thanks to @maxU, I know how to assign random control/treatment groupings to 2 groups; but what if I have 3 groups or more?

For example:

```
df.head()

customer_id | Group | many other columns
ABC             1
CDE             3
BHF             2
NID             1
WKL             3
SDI             2
JSK             1
OSM             3
MPA             2
MAD             1

pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Group'],values=["customer_id"],aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))

Group 1  : 270
Group 2  : 180
Group 3  : 330
```

I have a great answer, when I only have two groups:

```
df['Flag'] = df.groupby('Group')['customer_id']\
             .transform(lambda x: np.random.choice(['Control','Test'], len(x), 
                                                  p=[.5,.5] if x.name==1 else [.4,.6]))
```

But what if i want to split it this way:

- Group 1: 50% Control & 50% Test
- Group 2: 40% Control & 60% Test
- Group 3: 20% Control & 80% Test

@MaxU's answer is great, but unfortunately the split is not exact

```
d = {1:[.5,.5], 2:[.4,.6], 3:[.2,.8]}

df['Flag'] = df.groupby('Group')['customer_id'] \
             .transform(lambda x: np.random.choice(['Control','Test'], len(x), p=d[x.name]))
```

When i test it, I don't get exact splits.

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Group'],values=["customer_id"],columns=['Flag'], aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))

           Control  Treatment
Group 1:    138       132
Group 2:    78        102
Group 3:    79        251
```

Group 1 should be 135/135.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to split your `customer_id`'s into exact proportions, and not rely on chance. Here's one way to do that using `pandas.qcut` and `np.random.permutation`.

```
In [228]: df = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id': np.random.normal(size=10000), 
                             'group': np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], size=10000)})

In [229]: proportions = {'a':[.5,.5], 'b':[.4,.6], 'c':[.2,.8]}

In [230]: df.head()
Out[230]:
   customer_id group
0       0.6547     c
1       1.4190     a
2       0.4205     a
3       2.3266     a
4      -0.5691     b

In [231]: def assigner(gp):
     ...:     group = gp['group'].iloc[0]
     ...:     cut = pd.qcut(
                  np.arange(gp.shape[0]), 
                  q=np.cumsum([0] + proportions[group]), 
                  labels=range(len(proportions[group]))
              ).get_values()
     ...:     return pd.Series(cut[np.random.permutation(gp.shape[0])], index=gp.index, name='assignment')
     ...:

In [232]: df['assignment'] = df.groupby('group', group_keys=False).apply(assigner)

In [233]: df.head()
Out[233]:
   customer_id group  assignment
0       0.6547     c           1
1       1.4190     a           1
2       0.4205     a           0
3       2.3266     a           1
4      -0.5691     b           0

In [234]: (df.groupby(['group', 'assignment'])
             .size()
             .unstack()
             .assign(proportion=lambda x: x[0] / (x[0] + x[1])))
Out[234]:
assignment     0     1  proportion
group
a           1659  1658      0.5002
b           1335  2003      0.3999
c            669  2676      0.2000
```

What's going on here?

1. Within each group we call the function `assigner`
2. `assigner` grabs the group name and proportions from the predefined dictionary and calls `pd.qcut` to split into 0(control) 1(treatment)
3. `np.random.permutation` then shuffles the the assignments
4. Create this as a new column in the original dataframe

Comment: Thank you very much @Dan Frank, but it doesn't assign the control/treatment flag by group

Comment: @jeangelj I think I misunderstood your question ... so you're looking for an X%, 1-X% split within group 1, Y%, 1-Y% within group 2, etc.?

Comment: @jeangelj I've edited the code sample above and I believe it now handles your case

Comment: Hi Dan, I am getting this error suddenly: ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([   0,    0, 2621], dtype=int64).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg

Comment: @jeangelj check this answer, which has some details on the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158597/how-to-qcut-with-non-unique-bin-edges 

The problem is likely that one of your groups only has one customer in it

Answer (score 2):

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]:
  customer_id  Group
0         ABC      1
1         CDE      3
2         BHF      2
3         NID      1
4         WKL      3
5         SDI      2
6         JSK      1
7         OSM      3
8         MPA      2
9         MAD      1

In [14]: d = {1:[.5,.5], 2:[.4,.6], 3:[.2,.8]}

In [15]: df['Flag'] = \
    ...: df.groupby('Group')['customer_id'] \
    ...:   .transform(lambda x: np.random.choice(['Control','Test'], len(x), p=d[x.name]))
    ...:

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
  customer_id  Group     Flag
0         ABC      1  Control
1         CDE      3     Test
2         BHF      2     Test
3         NID      1  Control
4         WKL      3  Control
5         SDI      2     Test
6         JSK      1     Test
7         OSM      3     Test
8         MPA      2  Control
9         MAD      1     Test
```

Comment: thank you MaxU, is there any good documentation online to learn more about this approach?

Comment: @jeangelj, what approach do you mean - `.transform()`, `lambda ...`, `np.random.choice`, something else?

Comment: lambda with the categories d[x.name]

Comment: @jeangelj, [here are some examples about dictionaries](https://www.python-course.eu/dictionaries.php)

Comment: I just finished testing, but for my first group, where I have 270 in total; I get a split of 138 Control vs. 132 Treatment instead of 135/135

Comment: @jeangelj, yeah, `np.random` will not give you 100% exact distribution...

Comment: I see, would there be another approach that would?

Comment: @MaxU thank you! it seems that this cannot be accomplished with np.random

Comment: @MaxU, I am testing it and keep on getting this error ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1281 elements, new values have 1282 elements